# how is the concatenate dog utility installed?

Tags: repository, text-processing, official-repositories, add-apt-repository, cat

Where is the repo to install [dog](https://mydevelopedworld.wordpress.com/2012/06/30/linux-when-a-dog-is-better-than-a-cat/)?

> To get the command on Ubuntu you can just open a terminal and type:
>
> sudo apt-get install dog
>
> After the installation you can retrieve all the information you need
>   about dog...

I get:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo apt-get install dog
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dog
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
thufir@doge:~$
```

Just that it's the antagonist to `cat` makes it interesting.

My repos:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://ag-projects.com/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src   http://ag-projects.com/ubuntu xenial main
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ ls cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
ls: cannot access 'cat': No such file or directory
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/:
google-cloud-sdk.list  ring-nightly-man.list                webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.save
jitsi.list             webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list
thufir@doge:~$
```

Comment: There is no `dog` in Ubuntu repos. You an try to build it from source.

Comment: @Pilot6 well,  there's no `dog` for newer releases. It used to be there for older ones

Answer (score 3):

After searching for a while, I did find the launchpad page for `dog`: https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dog  The problem is that it is only available for trusty (14.04) , precise (12.04), and vivid(15.04). So you will have to grab source code, and build it from that:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/dog/trusty/files

Instructions on how to build it from source are in the README files supplied with the source code